# Adding images from a folder to website dynamically

Tags: javascript, image, loops, gallery, portfolio

I have a site which will have a gallery with 3 sections. Each section has up to 30 images. I will store the images in folders relating to the relevant sections (ie "img/gallery/category1", "img/gallery/category2" and "img/gallery/category3")

Basically instead of writing html to display each individual image, I would like to have a javascript loop which will look in the folder and display each image, and place the url within a predefined snippet of code, ie:

```
<div class="span4">
  <img src="img/gallery/category1/IMAGE-FILENAME1">
</div>

<div class="span4">
  <img src="img/gallery/category1/IMAGE-FILENAME2">
</div>
```

... etc, until all images from the folder have been processed... (also, I know I could be a bit smarter with the html above, but I want to communicate that I want each found image url to sit amongst a repeated snippet of code).

I'm still training in javascript, so I wondered whether there was a way I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative solution.

I wasn't quite ready to tackle AJAX, JSON or anything listed below just yet. So I decided to look into using PHP. Solution as folows:

I first of all used the following to go to and read the contents of the folder to an array:

```
$directory = "DIRECTORY"

$dirhandler = opendir($directory);

$nofiles=0;
while ($file = readdir($dirhandler)) {

if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')
{
  $nofiles++;
  $files[$nofiles]=$file;                
}}
```

And then using a foreach loop I iterated through the array, everytime echoing the html output which referenced the filename found.

Works perfectly.

Comment: a kind of solutions with php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129086/how-to-display-images-from-a-folder-using-php-php

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can't do this by iteself... however, if you had an XML or JSON formatted list of images and their respective locations, you could use ajax to get that file, parse it's contents, and create your markup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot look directly at the directory on the server from Javascript. You could make an AJAX call to the server to get the list (in XML or JSON), and then create and append a new div for each file as you loop through the response.